# Fubini's theorem applicaction

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

So, I thought I had a good grasp on how Fubini's theorem works, but then I found this exercise:

Let $\;f: [0,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function
Use Fubini's theorem to prove

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{a}\left(\int_{0}^{x}\left(\int_{0}^{y} f(z) dz \right)dy \right)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a}f(z)(a-z)^2dz 
\end{align}

So... I tried changing the integration order in every possible way, but the integral on the right never came out. I thought about using the fundamental theorem by defining $\;F(y) = \int_{0}^{y} f(z)dz$ and going from there, but to be honest I'm kind of clueless.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try doing the iterated integral in the following order
$$
\int_0^a f(z)\left[\int_z^a\left[\int_y^a 1\,dx\right]\,dy\right]\,dz.
$$

Comment: Oh, I think I got this now. So the whole point of this question is to represent the region in a equivalent way? For instance,

\begin{align}
R = \{(x,y,z) \in R^3 | y \leq x \leq a , z \leq y \leq a, 0 \leq z \leq a\}
\end{align}

This definition is equivalent to that implied by the integration limits in my original question, and the integral over it would be

\begin{align}
\int_{y}^{a} \int_{z}^{a} \int_0^{a} f(z) dz dy dz
\end{align}

And then we can apply Fubini's theorem

Answer (score 1):

When integrating over a triangle, you can use an indicator function of the triangle and apply Fubini Theorem:
$\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm d}$
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^a \int_0^x \int_0^y f(z)\,\dif z\,\dif y\,\dif x
&= \int_0^a \int_0^x \int_0^x [z \leq y]f(z)\,\dif z\,\dif y\,\dif x \\
&= \int_0^a \int_{[0,x]^2} [z \leq y]f(z)\,\dif (z \times y)\,\dif x \\
&= \int_0^a \int_0^x \int_0^x [z \leq y]f(z)\,\dif y\,\dif z\,\dif x \\
&= \int_0^a \int_0^x f(z) \left(\int_0^x [z \leq y] \dif y \right)\dif z\,\dif x \\
&= \int_0^a \int_0^x f(z) (x - z)\,\dif z\,\dif x \\
\end{align*}$$
Can you continue from here? $[\cdot]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: Huh, what strange notations.

Comment: Hm, I was not familiar with such notation. I take it that by "indicator function" you mean "characteristic function"?

Comment: @user396072 Yes. Indicator function is the same as characteristic function. $[z \leq y]$ can also be interpreted as the indicator of a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain of integration $S$ is determined by the inequalities
$$0\leq z\leq y\leq x\leq a\ ,\tag{1}$$
and is a simplex with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(a,0,0)$, $(a,a,0)$, $(a,a,a)$. The function to be integrated depends on $z$ alone. Fubini's theorem, aka "Cavalieri's principle", then says that
$$\int_S f(z) \>{\rm d}(x,y,z)=\int_0^a f(z)\,{\rm area}(S_z)\>dz\ ,\tag{2}$$
whereby $S_z$ is the shape cut out from $S$ by a horizontal plane at level $z$. Now from $(1)$ it follows that
$$S_z=\{(x,y)\,|\,z\leq y\leq x\}\qquad(0\leq z\leq a)\ ,$$
hence $S_z$ is a triangle of area ${1\over2}(a-z)^2$. Plugging this into $(2)$ gives
$$\int_S f(z) \>{\rm d}(x,y,z)={1\over2}\int_0^a f(z)\,(a-z)^2\>dz\ .$$